# Trouble on the instalation of the Cyanogen?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I'm trying to install Cyanogen on my Xperia L. I've done all the steps until [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_taoshan#Installing_CyanogenMod_on_Sony_Devices).

> [image]

My problem is on step 5, I don't know what I'm supposed to do. On the sideload method, it says to select **install zip > install zip from sideload**, but on my phone there is not such option.

In the push and install method it says to navigate to the phone's **mounts and storage**. But there is also no such option on the phone. What appears in my phone is the following:

- Reboot system now
- Apply update
- Wipe data/factory reset
- Wipe cache partition
- Reboot to bootloader
- Power down
- View recovery logs

**Progress:** I've uploaded the CM to my SD card. I've tried to run it using *Apply update > from sdcard1*. It runs for a while but it ends up in a screen that says:

> #### Cyanogen
>
> ## Recovery
>
> Install failed
>
> Finding update package...
>
> Opening update package...
>
> Installing update...
>
> This package is for device: C2105, C2014, C2105, C2104, taoshan
>
> this device is .
>
> E: Failed to install /sideload/package.zip
>
> Please take note of all the above lines for reports
>
> Installation aborted.

The problem here is that my device is an Xperia L C2104 (according to the box). I'm starting to think that I should upload it to */sdcard/0/*.

Comment: Have you flashed custom recovery?

Comment: @alb3rtano0012 Yes. In the guide I pointed, this step is after the custom recovery.

Comment: Instead of selecting sideload, select sd card. Once in there navigate to where the downloaded files are stored. Its been a while since I used CWM, I use teamwin. But after you tell it to install from sd card. There should be an option to change to external storage if you downloaded it to to the external sd card instead of the internal storage (which some phones call sd card) ---- Edit select apply update and see if it gives you the option to install zip from sdcard.

Comment: @jer3my Yes. The problem is that the CMOD wasn't in the card. I'll try to transfer it via ADB. Is it a good idea?

Comment: @Firelord Fixed.

Comment: Have you tried this method? http://techglen.com/2014/02/28/update-xperia-l-c2104-c2105-to-android-4-4-2-kitkat-with-cm-11-custom-rom/2/

Answer (score 5):

Pay attention to this particular part of the log:

```
This package is for device: C2105, C2014, C2105, C2104, taoshan
this device is .
```

The reason why this happens is that CyanogenMod ZIPs have the option to check the device it's being flashed on before it continues, so it won't get accidentally flashed on the wrong device.

If you look inside your ZIP and view the file `META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script`, you'll see something like this:

```
assert(getprop("ro.product.device") == "C2105" ||
       getprop("ro.build.product") == "C2014" ||
       ...
       abort("This package is for device: C2105, C2014, C2105, C2104, taoshan; this device is " + getprop("ro.product.device") + "."););
```

Now I find it weird that your recovery does not report the correct device model (`this device is .`). Your recovery might not have been built correctly.

Anyway, if you remove the entire `assert(` line up to `);`, the ZIP should flash just fine. Although if I were you, I'd take a bit more caution, since there is a possibility that the model info reporting isn't the only thing wrong with your recovery.

Comment: I'm trying to run it on my SD card instead of the internal memory. Does it present a problem?

Comment: @JesusChrist It shouldn't. As long as your phone can access the card (e.g. you can browse its contents in recovery), you should be able to flash any ZIPs on it. If you want, you can look for other ZIPs you can flash, such as themes, to confirm if your SD card works fine for this purpose.

Comment: Should the code be like this? http://pastebin.com/9qFEM3Ei

Comment: @JesusChrist Are you sure the `assert();` line is the only line you removed? If yes, then it's fine. Just remove the extra semicolon on the first line.

Comment: I used Mathematica to edit the text because of the coloring of parethesis. http://i.imgur.com/JPaCmsW.png

Comment: I tried last time and it didn't work. I'll try once more.

Comment: @JesusChrist Well you're supposed to edit it with an editor that supports Unix line endings (`LF`), such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org), because recoveries throw errors when they see Windows line endings (`CR+LF`) in the updater-script. But if you'd like to stick to Mathematica, then [this page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18325/lf-line-break-instead-of-crlf-when-exporting-text-files-on-windows) might be worth a look.

Comment: Got it. I'll get notepad++ now.

Comment: @JesusChrist Good luck! If you need help converting line endings, see [this page.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239551/eol-conversion-in-notepad)

Comment: It failed. It gave me: *E: footer is wrong E: signature verification failed*.