# How can I run a file on my phone, via the terminal on my computer?

Tags: cyanogenmod, shell

I'm doing [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/113542/13200). There is a detailed version of what I did. Now someone suggested me to install TWRP recovery, it could be installed via the playstore, but now I have no idea on how to make android run, it just opens in the CM recovery mode.

[The second option](https://twrp.me/devices/sonyxperial.html) seems to involve some kind of file transfer and manipulation of the files via a terminal on windows, but I have no clue on how to run files on my phone using Windows. I guess that the ADB is a tool for doing that, but until now I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Voyska, could you please at least mention the essentials in your post – not just the links alone? The links are fine for reference, but please do not expect us hunting them to figure out what you want to achieve ;)

Comment: `Izzy` is right. Please make corrections. // You have to boot into CM recovery mode, connect your phone into PC and type `adb shell` into PC's terminal/cmd (you would need ADB tool and phone drivers, try [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/is-there-a-minimal-installation-of-adb) or the web), find the Recovery partition name, and then figure out how to write `TWRP.img` (use `adb pull` to copy it from PC) to Recovery partition using `dd`. It probably would be like `dd if=/sdcard/TWRP.img  of=/dev/<RECOVERY_PARTITION_NAME>`.

Comment: If your phone supports flashing using fastboot mode, then just boot into it, connect phone into PC and issue (after drivers and fastboot tool installation) the command `fastboot flash recovery <YOUR_RECOVERY_FILE>`.